# Declare parameter type and default value from which php version?

Tags: php

I've heard that it's possible to declare the parameter type and default value to a function like the example below, but don't know from which php version this can be used? I got always this message 'Default value for parameters with a class type can only be null' inside my editor (PhpStorm).

I know it's possible to use return types like `: string` and `: void` from php 7.1.0 but can't find something about declaring the type and the default value add the same time.

**Example:**

```
 public function myExample(string $type = 'example') : string
 {
     return $type; 
 }
```

Comment: what's your project PHP version in PHPStorm? Is OK for me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of parameter type declarations doesn't impact the ability to set defaults. So this should work fine even if the IDE is complaining. If your PHP interpreter version in PhpStorm is set to an earlier PHP version then it will complain about type-hinting strings, because it thinks you're trying to set a default value for a class, which you can't do, so check that.